# create a list by literally using a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

For some reason I have a text file describing a lists of regular expressions

```
RegexRemove      = [ 'OC1.*','OC2.*','-UC.*','EG[0-9]{4,6}.*','_t[0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9]{0,2}$' ]

RegexReplace     = [ ['LA.*','LA'],['IF.*', 'IF'],['BH.*', 'BH'],['DP.*', 'DP'] ]
```

I like to read in the lines as string and convert them to the list as described in the text file.

The line are like source code defining the list, but they are part of a bigger textfile, which cannot read and interpreted as python.

I tried to convert them by replacing and splitting the string, but I always run into trouble, since commatas are used as delimiters for split and are part of the regular expression, too.
Can I read in only the line containing "Regex" and convert them to the lists described there by using some fancy functions?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the text? It looks like they are written as python code, so my first thought would be import. Ah, missed the part about it being part of a non-python document. There's eval, or you can parse it with your own regex.

Comment: Is the text file from a reliable source? Can you rule out the possibility that someone uses this file to enter malicious code? If so, you can try the `eval` statement to execute parts of it: `l = "RegexRemove      = [ 'OC1.*','OC2.*','-UC.*','EG[0-9]{4,6}.*','_t[0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9]{0,2}$' ]";  x = eval(l.split("=")[1])`

Comment: the text is reliable! It can be edited only by a small number of colleagues

Comment: @LydiavanDyke no need for `eval()` here - `ast.literal_eval()` will properly rebuild the list without security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the wanted lines (obviously you've already done with this), split them on the '=' char, and then pass the second part to `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "[ 'OC1.*','OC2.*','-UC.*','EG[0-9]{4,6}.*','_t[0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9]{0,2}$' ]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['OC1.*', 'OC2.*', '-UC.*', 'EG[0-9]{4,6}.*', '_t[0-9]{0,2}\\.[0-9]{0,2}$']
>>>
```

Comment: Nice. I will try to remember that for future problems.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval` to parse string as a python objects:

```
items = eval('[1,2,4]')
print(type(items),len(items), items) # output: <class 'list'> 3 [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Wrong answer. 1/ [`eval` is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), and 2/ it's not needed here.